# Vue not updating same type of component on v-if argument change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, conditional-statements, toggle

I have a custom Toggle component, made from scratch in Vue.

```
<template>

  <div :class="{Switch: true, disabled: disabled}" @click="toggle" :title="disabled ? disabledtitle : ''">

    <div :class="{Background: true, active: isToggled}"></div>
    <div :class="{Toggle: true, active: isToggled}"></div>

  </div>

</template>

<script>

  export default {

    name: 'Toggle',
    props: {

      toggled: {

        type: Boolean,
        default: false

      },
      disabled: {

        type: Boolean,
        default: false

      },
      disabledtitle: {

        type: String,
        default: ''

      }

    },
    data () {

      return {

        isToggled: false

      }

    },
    methods: {

      toggle () {

        if(this.disabled)
          return

        this.isToggled = !this.isToggled
        this.$emit('input', this.isToggled)

      }

    },
    mounted () {

      this.isToggled = this.toggled

    }

  }

</script>
...
```

It has multiple instances in an another component, like this:

```
<template>

    <div v-if="category === 'Basic'" class="Basic">

        <Toggle :toggled="config.isToggledThisOption" @input="updateConfig($event, 'isToggledThisOption')" />

    </div>

    <div v-else-if="category === 'Other'" class="Other">

        <Toggle :toggled="config.isToggledOtherOption" @input="updateConfig($event, 'isToggledOtherOption')" />

    </div>

</template>
...
```

There is also a menu, that switches between the categories (changes the `category` variable)
This works well, but the problem is, that the `toggled` prop does not update when switching between the categories.

**I managed to track it down, and the problem is the following:**

Whenever the value of the `category` changes, the `<Toggle />` component does not update. It always stays the same, even in inspect element, no updates happen. `mounted()` also doesn't get executed again, only when the page is reloaded (and even then, not all `<Toggle />`s' `mounted()` function get executed).

Do I need to add some kind of id/identificator to the component, so it gets re-mounted/re-rendered/re-initiated?

Comment: Can you also share the `Toggle` component code to check how `toggle` property is mapped to isToggled.

Comment: done, i added it, sorry

Comment: Completely get rid of `isToggled` and just use the prop instead. You don't need the line `this.isToggled = !this.isToggled` at all, just emit the correct new value and let the parent manage it. The `mounted` hook won't run again because the same component is being reused, which won't be a problem if you just use the `toggle` prop to decide the current state.

Comment: Alright, but how can I determinate what value should I send? Since I cant update prop values in Vue. @skirtle

Comment: You'd just emit `!this.toggled` .

Comment: ah thank, you, didn't remember that it will change thx

Comment: Can you show the code for `updateConfig` in the parent component?

Comment: solved it already, with previos answers, but thank you :)